# Запрет активации

Tags: html

Как запретить отправку формы при нажатии на Enter?

Нужно, чтобы отправка была возможна только мышкой.

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вы хотите испортить юзабилити?

Comment: Хочу решить проблему. При авторизации, когда данные введены, а курсор находится в поле ввода пароля и при нажатии Enter меняется раскладка клавиатуры на русскую и соответственно меняется пароль на русский.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Почему у вас Enter имеет какое-то отношение к раскладке?

Comment: Я сам не знаю. Возможно это Punto Switcher на ней воздействует.

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше разобраться с раскладкой, чем энтер запрещать. Это совершенно не нормально

Comment: Возможно Вы правы. Но с другой стороны Punto Switcher использует большая часть русскоязычного населения.

Comment: Неправда, ни я, ни кто-либо из моих знакомых не использует :D Думаю, если проблема на самом деле в Punto Switcher, правильнее всего будет отправить баг-репорт разработчикам этого самого Punto Switcher, потому что это всё равно не нормально

Comment: А пробелы в пароле как будете запрещать? Punto Switcher и на них реагирует

Comment: @andreymal это не баг, а фича. И она даже отключается https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSUpT.png

Comment: @AntonShchyrov видимо это не особо помогает https://yandex.ru/blog/punto/7302

Comment: @andreymal Лично у меня PS стоит, но выключен. Когда нужно - перевожу конкретное слово. По другому с ним работать невозможно. На каждый Ctrl-Space в IDE он мне переключал раскладку

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(form).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             event.preventDefault();
             return false;
        }
   });
});
```